# Как найти число независимых циклов в графе?

Tags: c++, графы

Я находил только поиск всех циклов, но мне нужны именно независимые циклы. На выходе должно быть число независимых циклов. Граф у меня задан списком смежности. Может кто-нибудь хотя бы псевдокод напишет.

Comment: Если граф связанный, то число циклов = `N-M-1`. Если не связанный - то предварительно выделить связанные подграфы.

Comment: спасибо,теперь стало понятнее